# Magento admin add product form

Tags: attributes

i have added two new attributes in product form for state and city (India only).
i want that when i select state, city select option will only show cities related to that state.
Is it possible. if yes than please tell me how. urgent.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can add a javascript file or a php generated js script in the product add/edit page that contains a json with all the states and cities.
Then attach an 'onchange' event on the state select that populates the city select with the correct values from the json.

You can try to simulate what happens for the address regions when changing the country (see checkout billing step as an example.)